# hook-length formula: "Fibonaccized" Part I

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, partitions, algebraic-combinatorics

Consider the Young diagram of a partition $\lambda = (\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_k)$.  For a square $(i,j) \in \lambda$, define the *hook numbers* $h_{(i,j)} = \lambda_i + \lambda_j' -i - j +1$ where $\lambda'$ is the *conjugate* of $\lambda$.

The [hook-length formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_length_formula) shows, in particular, that if $\lambda\vdash n$ then 
$$\text{$n!\prod_{\square\,\in\,\lambda}\frac1{h_{\square}}$} \qquad \text{is an integer}.$$
Recall the *Fibonacci numbers* $F(0)=0, \, F(1)=1$ with $F(n)=F(n-1)+F(n-2)$. Define $[0]!_F=1$ and $[n]!_F=F(1)\cdot F(2)\cdots F(n)$ for $n\geq1$.

> **QUESTION.** Is it true that 
>   $$\text{$[n]!_F\prod_{\square\,\in\,\lambda}\frac1{F(h_{\square})}$} \qquad \text{is an integer}?$$

Comment: More generally, this interesting question can be asked of any strong divisibility sequence instead of the Fibonacci sequence. But let's perhaps not abuse the notation $F\left(n\right)!$ for something that's not the factorial of $F\left(n\right)$.

Comment: I do agree, this was set as a "toy case". Notation altered as you pointed out.

Comment: Maybe call it $F!(n)$ instead of $F(n)!$.  How far has this been checked?

Comment: I have checked for partitions of $n\leq20$, but convinced well.

Comment: Maybe this expression can be obtained by a clever substitution of the $q$-hook length formula?

Comment: @darijgrinberg what is a strong divisibility sequence? Product of any $k$ consecutive guys is divisibly by the product of first $k$ guys?

Comment: For searching purposes: the product of consecutive Fibonacci numbers is sometimes referred to as a [fibonorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Fibonorial.html).

Comment: One can also consider asking an analogous question for [Bhargava factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhargava_factorial).

Comment: @FedorPetrov: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_sequence (though your condition is interesting, too).

Comment: @darijgrinberg this is not enough even for $a_5 a_6 a_7a_8$ to be divisible by $a_1a_2a_3a_4$, cf. diagram (4,4)

Comment: @FedorPetrov: Are you sure this is what the hook-length quotient would boil down to for $(4, 4)$? I'm getting a different result somehow.

Comment: @darijgrinberg it is even stronger, I think: $a_6a_7a_8$ should be divisible by $a_2a_3a_4$, that is not true when $a_k=2$ for $k$ divisible either by 2 or 3 and $a_k=1$ otherwise. My point was that if "binomial coefficients" should not be integer, then the "hook coefficients" also should not.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: But "binomial coefficients" from a strong divisbility sequence are integers, aren't they? Doesn't the usual $p$-valuative proof work?

Comment: @darijgrinberg ah, I missed the word strong. For a strong divisibility sequence, we may define the "cyclotomic factorization" $a_n=\prod_{d|n} b_d$ for certain integers $b_d$'s, then the proof from my answer works literally, right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sam is correct of course about $q$-hook formula. Below is a short self-contained proof not relying on such advanced combinatorics.

Denote $h_1>\ldots>h_k$ the set of hook lengths of the first column of diagram $\lambda$. Then the multiset of hooks is $\cup_{i=1}^k \{1,2,\ldots,h_i\}\setminus \{h_i-h_j:i<j\}$ and $n=\sum_i h_i-\frac{k(k-1)}2$.

Recall that $F(m)=P_m(\alpha,\beta)=\prod_{d|m,d>1}\Phi_d(\alpha,\beta)=\prod_d (\Phi_d(\alpha,\beta))^{\eta_d(m)}$, where

$\alpha,\beta=(1\pm \sqrt{5})/2$;

$P_n(x,y)=x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+\ldots+y^{n-1}$;

$\Phi_d$ are homogeneous cyclotomic polynomials;

$\eta_d(m)=\chi_{\mathbb{Z}}(m/d)$ (i.e., it equals to 1 if $d$ divides $m$, and to 0 otherwise).

Therefore it suffices to prove that for any fixed $d>1$ we have
$$
\sum_{m=1}^n \eta_d(m)+\sum_{i<j}\eta_d(h_i-h_j)-\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^{h_i}\eta_d(j)\geqslant 0.\quad (\ast)
$$
$(\ast)$ rewrites as
$$
[n/d]+|i<j:h_i\equiv h_j \pmod d|-\sum_{i=1}^k [h_i/d]\geqslant 0.\quad (\bullet)
$$
LHS of $(\bullet)$ does not change if we reduce all $h_i$'s modulo $d$ (and accordingly change $n=\sum_i h_i-\frac{k(k-1)}2$, of course), so we may suppose that $0\leqslant h_i\leqslant d-1$ for all $i$. For $a=0,1,\dots, d-1$ denote $t_a=|i:h_i=a|$. Then $(\bullet)$ rewrites as
$$
\left[\frac{-\binom{\sum_{i=0}^{d-1} t_i}2+\sum_{i=0}^{d-1} it_i}d\right]+
\sum_{i=0}^{d-1} \binom{t_i}2\geqslant 0. \quad (\star)
$$

It remains to observe that LHS of $(\star)$ equals to
$$
\left[\frac1d\sum_{i<j}\binom{t_i-t_j}2 \right].
$$

Comment: Nice.  So what does this integer count?

Comment: Yes, that was my plan to ask next.

Comment: @Fedor: what are $\alpha$ and $\beta$? What's the connection between $P_m$ and $\eta_d$, etc?

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan sorry, forgot to copy the notations from my previous Fibonacci answer. Hope now it is clear.

Answer (score 6):

This is a less elementary but maybe more conceptual proof, also giving some combinatorial meaning:
Use the formulas
$F(n) = \frac{\varphi^n -\psi^n}{\sqrt{5}}$, $\varphi =\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}, \psi = \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$. Let $q=\frac{\psi}{\varphi} = \frac{\sqrt{5}-3}{2}$, so that
$F(n) = \frac{\varphi^n}{\sqrt{5}} (1-q^n)$

Then the Fibonacci hook-length formula becomes:

\begin{align*}
f^{\lambda}_F:= \frac{[n]!_F}{\prod_{u\in \lambda}F(h(u))} = \frac{ \varphi^{ \binom{n+1}{2} } [n]!_q }{ \varphi^{\sum_{u \in \lambda} h(u)} \prod_{u \in \lambda} (1-q^{h(u)})}
\end{align*} 
So we have an ordinary $q$-analogue of the hook-length formula. Note that 
$$\sum_{u \in \lambda} h(u) = \sum_{i} \binom{\lambda_i}{2} + \binom{\lambda'_j}{2} + |\lambda| = b(\lambda) +b(\lambda') +n$$
Using the $q-$analogue hook-length formula via major index (EC2, Chapter 21) we have

\begin{align*}
f^\lambda_F = \varphi^{ \binom{n}{2} -b(\lambda)-b(\lambda')} q^{-b(\lambda)} \sum_{T\in SYT(\lambda)} q^{maj(T)} = (-q)^{\frac12( -\binom{n}{2} +b(\lambda') -b(\lambda))}\sum_T q^{maj(T)}
\end{align*}

Now, it is clear from the q-HLF formula that $q^{maj(T)}$ is a symmetric polynomial, with lowest degree term $b(\lambda)$ and maximal degree $b(\lambda) + \binom{n+1}{2} - n -b(\lambda) -b(\lambda') =\binom{n}{2} - b(\lambda')$ so the median degree term is
$$M=\frac12 \left(b(\lambda) +\binom{n}{2} - b(\lambda')\right)$$
which cancels with the factor of $q$ in $f^{\lambda}_F$, so the resulting polynomial is of the form
\begin{align*}
f^{\lambda}_F = (-1)^{M} \sum_{T: maj(T) \leq M } (q^{M-maj(T)} + q^{maj(T)-M}) \\
= (-1)^{M} \sum_{T} (-1)^{M-maj(T)}( \varphi^{2(M-maj(T))} + \psi^{2(M-maj(T)}) = 
\sum_T (-1)^{maj(T)} L(2(M-maj(T)))
\end{align*}
where $L$ are the Lucas numbers.

**byproduct of collaborations with A. Morales and I. Pak.

Comment: Nice, thank you. This would be even more fitting to the 2nd part of this question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327015/hook-length-formula-fibonaccized-part-ii  Therefore, do you like to post it there as well?

Comment: Thanks! I just pasted it there.