# hook-length formula: "Fibonaccized": Part II

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, partitions, algebraic-combinatorics

This is a natural follow-up to [my previous MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/326860/hook-length-formula-fibonaccized), which I share with Brian Hopkins.

Consider the Young diagram of a partition $\lambda = (\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_k)$.  For a square $(i,j) \in \lambda$, define the *hook numbers* $h_{(i,j)} = \lambda_i + \lambda_j' -i - j +1$ where $\lambda'$ is the *conjugate* of $\lambda$.

The [hook-length formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_length_formula) shows that if $\lambda\vdash n$ then 
$$n!\prod_{\square\,\in\,\lambda}\frac1{h_{\square}}$$
counts standard Young tableaux whose shape is the Young diagram of $\lambda$.

Recall the *Fibonacci numbers* $F(0)=0, \, F(1)=1$ with $F(n)=F(n-1)+F(n-2)$. Define $[0]!_F=1$ and $[n]!_F=F(1)\cdot F(2)\cdots F(n)$ for $n\geq1$.

> **QUESTION.** What do [these integers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/326860/hook-length-formula-fibonaccized) count? 
>   $$[n]!_F\prod_{\square\,\in\,\lambda}\frac1{F(h_{\square})}.$$

Comment: A  related problem is to find a combinatorial interpretation of the "Fibonomial coefficient" ${n\choose k}_F$. A solution (not very nice) appears in https://www.math.hmc.edu/~benjamin/papers/Fibonomial.pdf. This is related to the open problem of finding a "Fibonacci binomial poset" (*Enumerative Combinatorics*, vol. 1, second ed., Exercise 3.196(b)).

Comment: Thanks for the info, Richard!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is my answer to the original question (https://mathoverflow.net/a/327022/50244) whether these numbers are integers to begin with, it gives some combinatorial meaning as well:

Use the formulas
$F(n) = \frac{\varphi^n -\psi^n}{\sqrt{5}}$, $\varphi =\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}, \psi = \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$. Let $q=\frac{\psi}{\varphi} = \frac{\sqrt{5}-3}{2}$, so that
$F(n) = \frac{\varphi^n}{\sqrt{5}} (1-q^n)$

Then the Fibonacci hook-length formula becomes:

\begin{align*}
f^{\lambda}_F:= \frac{[n]!_F}{\prod_{u\in \lambda}F(h(u))} = \frac{ \varphi^{ \binom{n+1}{2} } [n]!_q }{ \varphi^{\sum_{u \in \lambda} h(u)} \prod_{u \in \lambda} (1-q^{h(u)})}
\end{align*} 
So we have an ordinary $q$-analogue of the hook-length formula. Note that 
$$\sum_{u \in \lambda} h(u) = \sum_{i} \binom{\lambda_i}{2} + \binom{\lambda'_j}{2} + |\lambda| = b(\lambda) +b(\lambda') +n$$
Using the $q-$analogue hook-length formula via major index (EC2, Chapter 21) we have

\begin{align*}
f^\lambda_F = \varphi^{ \binom{n}{2} -b(\lambda)-b(\lambda')} q^{-b(\lambda)} \sum_{T\in SYT(\lambda)} q^{maj(T)} = (-q)^{\frac12( -\binom{n}{2} +b(\lambda') -b(\lambda))}\sum_T q^{maj(T)}
\end{align*}

Now, it is clear from the q-HLF formula that $q^{maj(T)}$ is a symmetric polynomial, with lowest degree term $b(\lambda)$ and maximal degree $b(\lambda) + \binom{n+1}{2} - n -b(\lambda) -b(\lambda') =\binom{n}{2} - b(\lambda')$ so the median degree term is
$$M=\frac12 \left(b(\lambda) +\binom{n}{2} - b(\lambda')\right)$$
which cancels with the factor of $q$ in $f^{\lambda}_F$, so the resulting polynomial is of the form
\begin{align*}
f^{\lambda}_F = (-1)^{M} \sum_{T: maj(T) \leq M } (q^{M-maj(T)} + q^{maj(T)-M}) \\
= (-1)^{M} \sum_{T} (-1)^{M-maj(T)}( \varphi^{2(M-maj(T))} + \psi^{2(M-maj(T)}) = 
\sum_T (-1)^{maj(T)} L(2(M-maj(T)))
\end{align*}
where $L$ are the Lucas numbers.

**Remark.** This is a byproduct of collaboration with A. Morales and I. Pak.

Comment: Thanks for the post, Greta.

Comment: For the record: EC2=Stanley's "Enumerative Combinatorics" vol2 http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/.